# Perfom get query with value other than key

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is it possible for me to use the get query to query for a value other than the primary key? Cuz it seems I can only pass in the id column but is there no way in which i could perform the get query with a column other than the id column.
  Or can I just do this with a normal list query using maybe a filter or something? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can issue any DynamoDB query through AppSync. This provides a good introduction that covers PutItem, UpdateItem, and GetItem https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html. If you need to get multiple values by a key then you should use the DynamoDB Query operation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-query.

When using DynamoDB you need to bake your access patterns into the key schema(s) of your DynamoDB table and secondary indexes. For example, if you want to get a record by "email" then you should create a table where the **hash** key is "email". You would then be able to perform a GetItem operation by "email". If you need to query by email and have records sorted by date, then you would need a table where the **hash** key is "email" and the **sort** key is "date". Etc..

You are able to create secondary indexes and if you want to get a bit more advanced create composite index values and overload indexes to optimize your DynamoDB tables for your access patterns. Checkout the DynamoDB docs to learn more https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes.html.

Comment: Hey Mike. I've been really impressed with your knowledge on AppSync here and wondered if you'd be able to assist me on how to retrieve the hash key!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929031/how-do-i-use-a-global-secondary-index-to-get-the-id-of-a-user-in-my-table